# Dynamically connecting to Database in Java(Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I Want to connect to database at every http request(In every request i will be getting database details from user).Can anyone suggest how to do it using spring-boot-starter-jpa.

I can't use properties file for database configuration details.
because details i will be getting from http request dynamically.

I am using 2.0.0.M3 spring boot version.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to better use native JDBC code to connect with database and perform query. if you want to use spring data jpa then you have to create bean for `DataSource`, `EntityManagerFactory` and `JpaTransactionManager` at runtime.

Comment: Project requirement is to use ORM. i can't go with native jdbc code

Comment: @AnkitSingh then it is not possible with ORM in java. you must have to use jdbc template.

Answer (score 1):

If database details will come in every user request and you want connect database on every http request, then it is not preferable because you will not have even entity manager factory on application startup without database instantiation. However in this situation you would have to manually manage all those stuff. You have to create datasource, transaction manager , entity manager etc. instantiation and initialization on each request manually and register those with spring IOC container and after the request completion you have to manually remove (unregister) those instances from Spring IOC. You can alos create interceptors for that. But no one should do this manually process because it is so hactic and more complex and we are making burden of this instantiation to destroy of beans on our own.
Even spring manages it very well and we are making complexity by taking charge at our own.

Comment: This is the project requirement is there any alternative way to achieve this??

Comment: @Ankit Singh, but this process is very costly with respect to time and resources as well. Still what about repositories it will not created at runtime and it will throw exception and application will not started without entity manager (spring data jap repositories prerequisites it)

Comment: Ok thanks. So you suggest it cant be possible via ORM.(either via jpa or any other)We have to do it with spring-jdbc

Comment: @AnkitSingh, I does not mean that it is not possible. You must customize the Spring IOC Interfaces and classes usage as per your requirement which is not simple or easy to do, but it is not impossible. You must used to clear all your Spring IOC and Dependency injection concepts and then implement customized scenarios as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for all the support. i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be not proper to connect user's database instantly.I suggest to make an interface program to collect the dynamical data you need in one database.You cannot change the properties of connection parameters in your code.

Comment: i didn't get what you mean??

Answer (score 0):

You need to load properties file of spring boot in a class using `@ConfigurationProperties` anotation.

Also you need to call the database configuration api inside this class.

Answer (score 0):

Same requirement and I am sure all the database I connect to would have the same structure

Any solution till now?